# Intuition: expected value formula of a continuous random variable and Riemann sums

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, intuition

In my introductory probability class the expected value was given just by definition as

$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf(x) dx$$

with $f(x)$ representing the probability density function of the distribution.

But I was thinking about a way to correlate the idea in the discrete case with the one in the continuous case as follows (consider that I haven't studied measure theory yet) :

Form a partition of a interval $[a,b]$  so that $a=x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = b$ then we write the Riemann sum

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_{i}) x^* f(x^*)$$

with every $x^* \in [x_{i},x_{i+1}]$.

But now since $(x_{i+1}-x_{i}) f(x^*) \approx P(x_i<x<x_{i+1})$ and this approximation will improve more the points are close, we have something like the discrete case because

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_{i+1}-x_{i}) x^* f(x^*) \approx \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^*P(x_i<x<x_{i+1}) $$

More the points of the partition increase more a single point $x^*$ becomes the ''right'' value to multiply with $P(x_i<x<x_{i+1}) $ to obtain the expected value , and it's known that the left hand side becomes $\int_{a}^{b} xf(x) dx$, then letting $a \rightarrow -\infty$ and $b \rightarrow +\infty$ we are done.

I think the main problem with this reasoning is the interpretation of $x^*$ to become eventually the ''right'' value.

Do you consider this reasoning a valid intuition for the expected value?Thanks in advance

Comment: Without measure theory, it's simply a matter of definition. Your intuition seems decent to me as soon as you've accepted the notion of a distribution with density. Just know that you're basically defining E[X] as the limit of the expected value of some discretised version of $f$. Note, though, that the Riemann sum approximation mostly works well (in a purely formal sense) on bounded intervals.

Comment: Thanks fot your comment , can I ask you to be more specific about your last sentence because I don't catch really well what do you mean?

Comment: If you are familiar with delta functions, then you can use $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sum_k x_kp_k\delta (x-x_k)dx$. where $p_k$ is probability that $x=x_k$.

Comment: To add on to Woolier's comment, because I find it interesting: defining $x^* := x_i$ leads to the Itô integral. while having $x^* := 1/2 (x_i + x_{i+1})$ gives the Stratonovic integral, so there is not right value.

Comment: @Tortar I'm just saying that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\textrm{d}x$ is necessarily always an improper Riemann integral and thus *not* the limit of Riemann sums.

Comment: @haavbj If you wish to view this as a stochastic integral, it's an integral of the process $Y_t= tf(t)$ (which is deterministic) against the process $X_t=t$ (which is also deterministic). There is no diference between the "Stratonovich" and "Itô" formulations of such an integral.

Comment: Your intuition about the continuous distribution perfectly makes sense, and in fact, it roughly how the notion of probability density arises.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee, I think at least surely better than saying that for a continuous r.v. you just replace a sum with an integral, something I often heard :-)